# DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80004005 when registering Visual Fox Pro

Tags: com, visual-foxpro, regsvr32, dllregistration

When I try to register a Visual FoxPro DLL via an administrator command prompt:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32 C:\_temp\my.dll
```

on machines that are not mine I get the following error:

> The module "c:\_temp\my.DLL" was loaded but the call to
>   DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80004005.
>
> For more information about this problem, search online using the error
>   code as a search term.

I am able to register it on mine.  How do I get more info as to why it is failing?

Can I use my machine where it does register to back into why it doesn't register on other machines?

---

I've manually copied `MSVCR70.dll` into the `%systemroot%\SysWOW64` directory on the machine that it won't register on.

I've reviewed the dependencies with https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies and everything looks good.

[image: dependencies screenshot]

Comment: 0x80004005 (a.k.a E_FAIL) is the most generic error that exists, so it tells us nothing. Maybe you can try to use Process Monitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon and examine what registry keys or file access errors you get (you can filter on the process exe name to limit the number of events)

Comment: .  Filter by `regsvr32.exe` I would assume? @SimonMourier

Comment: Depends on what you use for registration, but yes if you use regsvr32.exe

Comment: The most direct way is to set a breakpoint on `my!DllRegisterServer` and see what happens. If you can't do this, then add logging to your `DllRegisterServer` function.

Comment: It's a VFP DLL so I didn't write any `DllRegisterServer` code.  I assume it is generated for me?  @RaymondChen

Comment: 1,250 events for the failing, 2,592 events for the succeeding one.  Not sure how to track down the failure though.  Removing `SUCCESS` still leaves a lot of entries in both.  Thoughts?  @SimonMourier

Comment: What version of VFP? For the most recent, you need MSVCR71, not 70.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of VFP it was compiled against.  @TamarE.Granor

Comment: I'm guess VFP 7 as I searched the registry for this DLL and I see `VFP7R.DLL` under `{CLSID}\Foxruntime` @TamarE.Granor

Comment: If there are less events for fail than success, you could try to find when/where it fails comparing with success, and then move backwards looking at errors or NAME_NOT_FOUND. But it's indeed not easy because there are a lot of non fatal failures or NAME_NOT_FOUND. You can also activate file events and see if it's looking for a specific file (specific to your app or to VFP) and can't find it.

Comment: Okay, for VFP 7, MSVCR70 is the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon the comment from [Tamar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259592/tamar-e-granor), I searched the registry for this DLL on a machine where I could register it and I found `{CLSID}\Foxruntime\VFP7R.DLL`.

I installed the VFP 7 Runtime from [here (github.com/VFPX/VFPRuntimeInstallers)](https://github.com/VFPX/VFPRuntimeInstallers/blob/master/VFP7SP1RT.exe) and I was able to register the DLL

Answer (score 1):

I have typically found and associated 0x80004005 with permissions.  Did you try to run the DOS prompt AS ADMINISTRATOR?

Also, VFP is ONLY a 32-bit application/dll, it was never 64-bit support, so you probably need the files in System32, not SysWow64.

Permissions might also need to be confirmed for those USING the dll.  Ex: you install with admin permissions to drive

C:\SomePath\YourVFP.dll

Make sure the end-user has permissions to this path/file as well.

Aside from the above points... Do you have the VFP SOURCE code / project to build the DLL?

Comment: Yes, admin cmd prompt.  `SysWOW64` is where `MSVCR70.dll` is on my machine.  And [SysWOW64: Windows System folder (system directory) for 32-bit files](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm)

Comment: I have a copy of the source but I'm not confident it is accurate so I'm trying to use the DLL that is currently used in PROD.